# Не появляются кнопка и метка

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

Делаю программу которая будет показывать ось составлять разные оси.Не выводятся кнопки.
Код:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
root.title("Построение графика функции")
root.geometry('1020x620')
canvas = Canvas(root,width = 1020, height = 620, bg ="#1D2456")
canvas.grid()
for y in range(21):
    k = 50 * y
    canvas.create_line(10+k,610,10+k,10,width =1,fill='#2F8856')
for x in range(13):
    k = 50 * x
    canvas.create_line(10,10+k,1010,10+k,width =1,fill='#2F8856')
canvas.create_line(310,10,310,610,width = 1 , arrow= FIRST, fill = "white")
canvas.create_line(310,310,1010,310,width = 1 , arrow= LAST, fill = "white")
def roots():
    yr = ttk.Label(root,text = "Ось x")
    y1 = ttk.Button(root,text="Назначить")
    yr.grid()
    y1.grid()
roots()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы создаете окно с конкретным размером, потом создаете `Canvas` с тем же размером. Для `Button` и `Label` просто не остается места. Уберите строку `root.geometry('1020x620')`, тогда кнопка и метка появятся.